# With an Azure static website, is there a way to identify how many times a resource is accessed?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to pull analytic data on how frequently any static resource is accessed/downloaded. (I'm thinking Word documents, PDFs, audio files, video files)

Right now, the files are on a VM behind `nginx`, so the team can programmatically analyze the access logs.

We'd like to migrate this website to an Azure python WebApp, and it seems smart to put the static files into blob storage. I just can't find a way to get the information we need.

On top of that, it seems Azure doesn't have Application Insights for their Linux WebApps, which is their recommended way of hosting python.

Anyone know of a way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** There are 2 ways to get the data:

**1**.Nav to azure portal -> Monitoring -> Metrics. Then click `"Add metric"` -> for `"metric namespace"`, select `"blob"`; for `"metric"`, select `"Transactions"`; for `"aggregation"`, select `"sum"`. Screenshot as below:

[image]

**Then** you need to add a filter. Click the `"Add filter"` button -> for `"property"`, select `"API name"`; for `"Values"`, select `"GetBlob"`. Then you can see the total requests number to blobs. A screenshot as below:

[image]

**2**.Another way, you can log all the requests, then check the logs.

Nav to azure portal -> Monitoring(classic) -> Diagnostic settings(classic) -> then in the "blob properties", select some values, then click save button. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Note that all the logs are stored in the $log container in blob storage, but you should use [storage explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=windows) to see this $log container(it's not displayed in azure portal). Then you can see all the requests to the blobs. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and illustrations. Sadly, it doesn't exactly cover my use case. 

I'm looking to count requests for static resources that may not be initiated from a web page I control. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisMay can you give an example of the static resources? and how does the static resource being accessed?

Comment: This site is a CMS, and some of the users upload Wod Documents, audio files, videos, PDFs, etc into into a folder. From there, many of them are linked to from other websites, without ever hitting an HTML page on this website.

Comment: @ChrisMay, thanks for your explanation. Just want to confirm, so you just want to get the total number of requests(get request) of a file, like the audio, PDF?

Comment: @ChrisMay, please see the updated answer. And let me know if any issues :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Ivan! I will look into this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can. Check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal#metrics for guidance.

The metrics section can help you with that. You can also include application insights telemetry from the javascript side of your website. Check documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript

Comment: From what I can tell in the Metrics view, I can only see the sum of bytes transferred (Egress), but not the files accessed.